# How to write a plugin in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to write a new plugin in Gazebo standalone version, but I don't know how to start. Could anyone give me any advice? This plugin is for a home made actuator. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5615/how-to-write-a-plugin-in-gazebo/) by [engine_](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/669/engine_/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's also tutorials for more recent versions of gazebo here:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#Plugins

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0